# Bootstrap: hide links on navbar collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make links in my navbar disappear on the navbar's collapse.

I've got two lists of links inside my navbar:

```
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
      <ul class ="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><%= link_to 'Home', '#home' %> </li>
        <li><a href="#food">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#drinks">Drinks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#enter">Entertainment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        ...
      </ul>
    </div>
```

As expected, when my navbar collapses, I get them collapsed into two sections, like this:

[image: collapsedOpened]

(I added an "extra" home link myself, on the collapsed navbar, in some other code.)

What I want, though, is this:

[image: collapseRemoved]

I want the top links (Home, Food, Drinks, Entertainment), to disappear on a navbar collapse. If I remove the "navbar-collapse" class from them, they just (rather ugligly) stay in the navbar. I was thinking about removing them with jQuery (on .navbar-collapse show), but that seems overkill. It's also problematic if the navbar uncollapses again, since then I would have removed the links from the navbar! Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnxqpwjc/), with what I have now. Here's a [editted JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnxqpwjc/4) with me doing what I want, but with jQuery.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you need exactly. You should try creating an example of what you are trying to achieve on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or at least try doing it yourself and show us what you came up with.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I added an additional screenshot to explain what I'm trying to do. I'll go ahead and make a JSFiddle as well, now. Thanks!

Comment: We need to see what you've tried with jQuery or javascript, can you added your attempted code!

Comment: Added a JSFiddle at the end. Thanks!

Comment: add `hidden-xs` on your navbar that you don't want to be there on small devices. Look at the responsive utilities.

Comment: @dvdhsu It's good to create a JSFiddle but it's better to paste the JavaScript here anyway.

Comment: @dvdhsu And you didn't even attempt to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a responsive utility class `hidden-xs.`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jnxqpwjc/2/

```
    <div class="hidden-xs collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="removeOnCollapse">
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#food">Food</a></li>
        <li><a href="#drinks">Drinks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#enter">Entertainment</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the top links to disappear on a navbar collapse and to display them again when the navbar is fully displayed you could try this:

```
$('.navbar-left').on('show.bs.collapse', function() { $('.navbar-left').hide(); });
$('.navbar-left').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() { $('.navbar-left').show(); });
```

If you want to remove them and not display them never again you should try:

```
$('.navbar-left').on('show.bs.collapse', function() { $('.navbar-left').remove(); });
```

Provided that you only have one element using '.navbar-left' of course.

Comment: Bootstrap has this built in. No need for jQuery

Comment: Thanks! This works as well, but the built-in "hidden-xs" is cleaner. Thanks, though!